# Can you use JavaScript "in" operator to test for multiple conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to test if one or more strings is equal to an object key. For example:

```
if(("apple" || "oranges) in fruitObj) {
    console.log(fruitObj);
}
```

My end goal is to loop through all the strings in an array, and test if any of the strings are inside "fruitObj".

Comment: @Teemu `fruitObj` isn't an array in this question.  "i'm trying to test if one or more strings **is equal to an object key.**"

Comment: It's important to understand that `'apple' || 'orange'` is itself an expression. It evaluates to the first value, `'apple'`, since it's truthy. This sort of logical `||` expression can never be used to check against multiple values in an array or object.

Comment: @hellyale I'm not testing if a string is in a list though. I'm testing if a string is a key in an object. So the question in that link is fairly different from mine...I think. Question has been answered though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want the array `some` function.

```
if (["apple", "oranges"].some(str => str in fruitObj)) {
   console.log(fruitObj);
}
```

Comment: Good Answer! You would think there would be a more terse way to pull this off though.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Dave. Forgot about the some() method.

Comment: Most concise answer. In terms of performance on large objects, if you just need to know it at least one key matches, it's even better to use `.find()` because "If such element is found, find immediately returns the value of that element": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find. In short, `.some()` would check every key, where `.find()` will stop at first match.

Comment: @NicoPrat as far as I know, both `find` and `some` return early (ie: as soon as they find a match). the difference is that `find` returns the element, whereas `some` returns a `boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

Another variation: you could use `Array.prototype.includes` (introduced in ES7 / ES2016):

```
if (Object.keys(fruitObj).some(key => ["apple", "oranges"].includes(key)) {
    console.log(fruitObj);
}
```

This is assuming that `fruitObj` doesn't contain any inherited properties (since those wouldn't be returned by `Object.keys()`).

After writing this though, I realized that Dave's answer is more concise and readable.

There is a polyfill available for older browsers here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill

Answer (score 0):

The strict answer to your question is: No, you cannot use the `in` operator to test against "combined" values, but of course you can "combine" individual checks:

```js
var mycar = { make: 'Honda', model: 'Accord', year: 1998 };
if ('make' in mycar || 'model' in mycar)
  console.log("found it");
else
  console.log("not there");
```

You can create a simple function for that and add it to the `Object`:

```js
Object.prototype.contains = function(values) {
  if (values instanceof Array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i] in this)
        return true;
    }
  } else if (values in this)
    return true;
  return false;
}

var mycar = { make: 'Honda', model: 'Accord', year: 1998 };
if (mycar.contains(['make', 'model']))
  console.log("found it");
else
  console.log("not there");
```

Note that although the `contains` function is also added to arrays, you cannot use it to search for strings in an array of strings. The `in` operator only compares to the keys of the object not its values. The keys of an array are its indexes, so you can only do `myArray.contains[0, 5]` which will check if one of those indexes exists in the array.